# Xpath selector not working in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract the text from this Xpath:

```
//*/li[contains(., "Full Name")]/span/text()
```

from this webpage:
http://votesmart.org/candidate/biography/56110/norma-smith#.V9SwdZMrKRs

I've tested it in Google Chrome's Console (which works), as with many other variations of the Xpath, but I can't get it to work with Scrapy. My code only returns "{}".

Here's where I have been testing it in my code, for context:

```
 def parse_bio(self, response):  
    loader = response.meta['loader']
    fullnameValue = response.xpath('//*/li[contains(., "Full Name")]/span/text()').extract()
    loader.add_value('fullName', fullnameValue)
    return loader.load_item()
```

The problem isn't my code (I don't think), it works fine with other (very broad) Xpath selectors. But I'm not sure what's wrong with the Xpath. I have JavaScript disabled, if that makes a difference. 
Any help would be great!

Edit: Here is the rest of the code to make it more clear:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Selector
from votesmart.items import LegislatorsItems, TheLoader



class VSSpider(Spider):
name = "vs"
allowed_domains = ["votesmart.org"]
start_urls = ["https://votesmart.org/officials/WA/L/washington-state-legislative"]


def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath('//h5/a/@href').extract():
        person_url = response.urljoin(href)
        yield Request(person_url, callback=self.candidatesPoliticalSummary)

def candidatesPoliticalSummary(self, response): 
    item = LegislatorsItems()
    l = TheLoader(item=LegislatorsItems(), response=response)


   ...
   #populating items with item loader. works fine

    # create right bio url and pass item loader to it
    bio_url = response.url.replace('votesmart.org/candidate/', 
                                   'votesmart.org/candidate/biography/')
    return Request(bio_url, callback=self.parse_bio, meta={'loader': l})

def parse_bio(self, response):  
    loader = response.meta['loader']
    print response.request.url
    loader.add_xpath('fullName', '//*/li[contains(., "Full Name")]/span/text()')
    return loader.load_item()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem! Many pages on the site were login protected, and I wasn't able to scrape from pages that I couldn't access in the first place. Scrapy's form request did the trick. Thanks for all the help (especially the suggestion of using `view(response)`, which is super helpful).

Answer (score 0):

The expression is working for me in the shell perfectly as is:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://votesmart.org/candidate/biography/56110/norma-smith#.V9SwdZMrKRs"
In [1]: response.xpath('//*/li[contains(., "Full Name")]/span/text()').extract()
Out[1]: [u'Norma Smith']
```

Try using the `add_xpath()` method instead:

```
loader.add_xpath('fullName', '//*/li[contains(., "Full Name")]/span/text()')
```

Comment: I tried the add_xpath method, it still won't work for me. Within the method I printed/checked the response url, so it isn't the url that is the problem, either.

Comment: @KatherineCavanaugh I've checked it as well and the xpath works fine. Are you sure you are able to download the page properly? once you `scrapy shell url` do you get `200` status code? Try disabling javascript in your browser and call `view(response)` and see the page in your browser if it's not missing anything. Your source might be distorted for one reason or another. Also it's possible that this website is blocking you.